# Retrieve part of a string from a full text

Tags: java, java-8

I hve a string variable which contains a text along with some dates in it. Now I would like to retrieve the date from the text. How I can do it.

```
String a ="I am ready at time -S 2019-06-16:00:00:00 and be there"
```

Now I would like to retrieve `2019-06-16:00:00:00` from there. Date format will always be in the same format but I need to retrieve the date only from the text.

Comment: [Regex?](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a regex matcher with the pattern:

```
\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}
```

Sample code:

```
String a = "I am ready at time -S 2019-06-16:00:00:00 and be there";
String pattern = "\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(a);
while (m.find()) {
     System.out.println("found a timestamp: " + m.group(0));
}
```

Comment: You're right, I thought you had parentheses in your regex. My bad.

Comment: Thanks. One more thing. 
 String a ="I am ready at time -S 2019-06-16:00:00:00 and -n03 be there"
In this string I need to retrieve the value of the -n. This -n can be any where in the text just like the date solution. ALso the format of the -n value can be

-n15  -- No Space after -n

-n 15 -- Space after -n

My text may start with -n or -n can be in middle or end..

Please help with the regex for the same

Comment: `One more thing` ... please don't change your question after others have already answered.

Comment: I am just asking one more additional information only. This question is anwered.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use regular expressions for that, like this:

```java
private static final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})");
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String a = "I am ready at time -S 2019-06-16:00:00:00 and be there"

    // create matcher for pattern p and given string
    Matcher m = p.matcher(a);

    // if an occurrence if a pattern was found in the given string...
    if (m.find()) {
        // ...then you can use group() methods.
        System.out.println(m.group(0));
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to provide what matcher he needs to use.

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = "I am ready at time -S 2019-06-16:00:00:00 and be there";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<date>\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}):(?<time>\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2})");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

if(matcher.matches()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group("date"));  // 2019-06-16
    System.out.println(matcher.group("time"));  // 00:00:00
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the regular expression to retrieve the date from the text.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String a = "I am ready at time -S 2019-06-16:00:00:00 and be there";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9]{4}[-][0-9]{1,2}[-][0-9]{1,2}[:][0-9]{1,2}[:][0-9]{1,2}[:][0-9]{1,2}");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(a);
    while(matcher.find()){
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }
}
```

Comment: This text may contains other numeric value also. 
Actual string would be like "I am ready at time -S 2019-06-16:00:00:00 and be there -k 2 Heldlo -a02 Done"; Now this paramter can be in different places in the text and I need to fecth value of -d -k -a